# How to update a row based on condition from a case expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a CASE expression in an SQL query. I want to create a new column as rank based on the case expression and update only the row which has max date for login.

```
select A.*,
  CASE          
    WHEN A.COUNT = 1        
    THEN 'rank1'  
    -- I want to give the condition here saying update the row
    -- which has the latest login date with 'rank1' .. now it is
    -- updating all the row which has count as 1
    else 'rank2' end as Rank 
from table A
```

How can I add a condition to the above code to update only the column which has count 1 and latest login date compared to other rows within the same registration?

End table should look like this:

```
count  regID   login        rank
1      221      10 april 16     rank1
1      221      9 april 16      rank2
1      221      8 april 16      rank2
1      366      8 march 16      rank2
1      366      1 feb 16        rank2
1      366      22 april 16     rank1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for `row_number()`:

```
select A.*,
       (case when a.count = 1 and
                  row_number() over (partition by a.count, regid order by login desc) = 1
             then 'rank1'
             else 'rank2'
        end) as rank
from table A;
```

Comment: how to add multiple when and then condition above? thanks for this

Comment: And problem with this code is it only updates the latest last login from the entire rows as rank 1 and ignore the rest. I want to update rank on regID bases. For reg ID 221 there will be one rank1 and similarly for 366 another rank1 will be there. Above code doesn't look it this way. please help

Comment: @rookie . . . That column goes in the `partition by`.  I thought the only column of interest for splitting the data was `count`.